# RecyclerView crashing on Android 6

Tags: android, crash, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to use RecyclerView on my app and it keep crashing on Android 6. Could you guys help me?

I tried to debug and the app crashes in the onCreateView of the Fragment. It tries to inflate the fragment and then crashes.

Something I read on the internet and stop the crashing is removing the android:scrollbars="vertical", but, after removing it, it says " No adapter attached; skipping layout".

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.canScrollVertically()' on a null object reference
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.computeVerticalScrollRange(RecyclerView.java:1581)
at android.view.View.onDrawScrollBars(View.java:13924)
at android.view.View.onDrawForeground(View.java:17657)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16189)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.draw(RecyclerView.java:3171)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15174)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16181)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15174)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.drawChild(DrawerLayout.java:1229)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16181)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15174)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16181)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2690)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15174)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:281)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:287)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:322)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2615)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2434)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2067)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my problem. I was using a wrong fragment. It has a similar name, but, it didn't the trick with RecylerView and the Layout Manager.

The right Fragment has this

```
    protected RecyclerView recyclerView;
private List<Noticia> noticias;
private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_noticia, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    return view;
}
```